# Unable to access current user in ASP.NET Core project with IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, identity, httpcontext

I have a `UserService` in my ASP.NET Core project of my Blazor web assembly solution (.NET 6) in which I'm trying to access the current logged in user to determine the ID of the company they work for.

UserService.cs

```
public class UserService
{
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal User => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;

        public IEnumerable<UserDto> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = new List<UserDto>();

            var companyId = GetCompanyId();

            users = _userManager.Users.Select(u => new UserDto()
            {
                CompanyId = u.CompanyId,
                Email = u.Email,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                Id = u.Id,
                DeleteDate = u.DeleteDate
            }).Where(u => u.DeleteDate == null && u.CompanyId == companyId.Result).ToList();

            return users;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetCompanyId()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            return user.CompanyId;
        }
}
```

As you can see I've injected `IHttpContextAccessor` into the constructor for my `UserService` and I've also registered `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in my `Program.cs` file (code also shown below).

Whenever my code hits the `return user.CompanyId;` line of my `UserService`, it errors with a null reference exception as the user is always null. I'm logged in and successfully authenticated by the point I try and get it to run this code.

Am I missing something from my `Program.cs` file or I have done something wrong in the `UserService` itself?

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how and where you use the UserService to get the user ID?

Comment: Yes of course. I inject it into a Razor component and then call the GetUsers method from a method within the component. The component itself is then embedded in an Index.cshtml page following the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

to get userId by using contextAccessor try below code, instead of usermanager

```
var userId=_httpContextAccessor.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: To make your answer more clear, the UserManager is part of the authentication system and is only used if you opt-in to it and set it up when the user logs in. Otherwise, you cannot simply inject it like you do with the IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Even removing UserManager from the equation entirely, _httpContextAccessor.User is still null. It looks as though it picks up an identity (Identities Count = 1), but when I expand open System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity everything is either null or 0.

Comment: When I try to use   var userid = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; I get the same null error. I added it to my IndexModel. I'm using RazorPages, not Blazor but how httpContextAccessor is referenced should be the same.